# Smoothness and its relation to infinte differentiability

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, continuity, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Why does a function having any 'kinkiness' not infinitely differentiable?

Some of the functions(e.g. $f(x) = (|x|)^{k}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$) belong to the class of $C^{k-1}$ functions(i.e. for these functions $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$, $...$ , $f^{k-1}(x)$ exist and are continuous). They are able to evade up to $(k-1)^{th}$ differentiation. What is inherent in the idea of differentiation and its continuity which is able to capture any 'kinkiness' behavior of the function?

Comment: One could say that's an alternate, imprecise way of characterizing $C^{k-1}$ functions: they're hiding some "kinkiness" or other pathologies in the $k-1$th derivative.  If you mean more specifically that something like $|x|$ can't exist at all in a $C^\infty$ function then that's a bit more slippery and depends on how you're allowed to modify it.  E.g. using a smooth kernel convolution would turn $|x|$ into $C^\infty$

Comment: @EliJohnson Well, convolution turns any continuous — indeed, $L^1$ — function into a smooth function.